# django sorl create thumb on save

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I need to create 3 type of thumb when I upload a photo.
700x500, 700x700, 500x400 – so when I'll use on the template something like this:

```
{% thumbnail photo.file "700x500" crop="center" as im %}
```

or

```
{% thumbnail photo.file "700x700" crop="center" as im %}
```

or

```
{% thumbnail photo.file "500x400" crop="center" as im %}
```

The first user will not wait and the thumbnail template tag should get the thumb from the cache. Right?

This is my model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
  def __unicode__(self):
    return 'photo #%s' % (self.pk)  

  file = ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
  featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

"""
    Make thumb on save
"""
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:

        #700x500
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
        resized = get_thumbnail(self.file, "700x500", crop="center")
        self.file.save(resized.name, ContentFile(resized.read()), True)

        #700x700
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
        resized = get_thumbnail(self.file, "700x700", crop="center")
        self.file.save(resized.name, ContentFile(resized.read()), True)

        #500x400
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
        resized = get_thumbnail(self.file, "500x400", crop="center")
        self.file.save(resized.name, ContentFile(resized.read()), True)

    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Make sense?

Actually without creating the thumb after saving but using only the templatetags thumbnail on the template my server sometimes goes down because I have a lot of number of thumb to create.

Comment: Use an async task queue (Celery), and create the thumbnails when uploading the file.

Comment: I know that Celery could be the best solution but ATM I need to create the thumb directly without Celery. Btw, How? Calling get_thumbnail(self.file, "500x400", crop="center") ?

Comment: Yes call the get_thumbnail from a task, if you need to throttle operations Celery provides the means.

Comment: If first I use {% thumbnail photo.file "500x400" crop="center" as im %} and THEN I use get_thumbnail(file, "500x400", crop="center") on the same file. Should I get the result from cache, right? Seems that is regenerating everytime the thumb because the function is very slow to return something. lmk, thanks.

Comment: @petkostas any ideas?